# This query will output the details of students who passed in ExamID 1 and ExamID 3. I want to show the mark they got in each exam also. How?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, subquery, intersect

How do I update the sql query below containing joins and subquery so that i can get the marks of **ExamID=1** and **ExamID=3** also in the final result set?

```
SELECT DISTINCT st.StudentID,st.Name 
FROM Students st 
INNER JOIN StudentMarks stm ON st.StudentID=stm.StudentID
WHERE st.StudentID IN(SELECT stm.StudentID 
                      FROM StudentMarks stm 
                      INNER JOIN Exam ex ON stm.ExamID=ex.ExamID
                      WHERE stm.Mark>=ex.MinMarkForPass AND stm.ExamID=1
INTERSECT
SELECT stm.StudentID 
FROM StudentMarks stm 
INNER JOIN Exam ex ON stm.ExamID=ex.ExamID
WHERE stm.Mark >= ex.MinMarkForPass AND stm.ExamID=3)
```

Comment: Do you want the students who take ***both exams***?

Comment: The students who passed in both exams will be shown by the above query. I want to show the mark each got on both the exams also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `INTERSECT`, you can do this:

```
WITH BothCTE
(
    SELECT stm.StudentID 
    FROM StudentMarks stm 
    INNER JOIN Exam ex ON stm.ExamID=ex.ExamID
    WHERE stm.Mark >= ex.MinMarkForPass AND stm.ExamID IN(1, 3)
    GROUP BY StudentID
    HAVING(DISTINCT ExamID) >= 2
)
SELECT st.StudentID, st.Name, stm.Mark
FROM Students st 
INNER JOIN StudentMarks stm ON st.StudentID = stm.StudentID
WHERE st.StudentID IN(SELECT StudentID FROM BothCTE);
```

The `CTE` will give you those students who took both the exams, then you can join these results with the marks table to get the marks of the students.